# Open source machine vision code to locate a human in a room

Tags: open-source, computer-vision, robotics

Has anybody seen a resource covering specifically the use of machine vision for locating a human in a room, including cases where they may be partially obscured?  I know about OpenCV and other machine vision packages, but I'm looking for a paper/library/code example that focuses solidly on identifying a human in a room; something that is readily integrated into code rather than being a rough idea that would require weeks or months of tweaking or enhancing to do a reasonable job of succeeding at the task.  I'd prefer something that does not require binocular vision and can work with a single camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: you should read [this](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf) about human detection. Then you can find/use opencv code implementing the training step of this kind of detector. You will need to access to a database for training like [INRIA Person dataset](http://pascal.inrialpes.fr/data/human/).

Second: if you need to handle partial obstruction, you may need to implement a human body tracker that can handle this problem. [Particle filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter) could do the work.

If you have problems with implementation feel free to ask more specific questions.